A Question about what counts as a qualified covered call for tax purposes
Below is a quote from IRS Pub 550:

Qualified covered call options and optioned stock.
A straddle is not
subject to the loss deferral rules for straddles if both of the
following are true.

All the offsetting positions consist of one or
more qualified covered call options and the stock to be purchased from
you under the options.
The straddle is not part of a larger
straddle.


What is the purpose of the second line? Could somebody give me an example of a case where
a qualified covered call is subject to the loss deferral rules because it is part off a larger straddle?

This is above my pay grade.  Perhaps this might be relevant? https://www.mayerbrown.com/files/Publication/315046a3-2648-4af0-a4ac-16a53c5f088b/Presentation/PublicationAttachment/421fe726-ee30-42c9-9c7a-1ec2ab1095bc/ART-Leeds_Mixed_Straddles_0714.pdf?utm_source=mondaq&utm_medium=syndication&utm_term=tax&utm_content=articleoriginal&utm_campaign=article

You might have better luck getting an explanation on the Options BB at EliteTrader.com (if it's still active)
